# How to convert hex into UTF-8 on ruby (1.8.7)?

Tags: ruby, utf-8

For example how to create UTF-8 character from the following: "0x63 0xcc 0x8c"?

I understand that ruby 1.9 has better UTF-8 but this question is for ruby 1.8.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby String unpack? http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.src/M001112.html.

For example:

```
"\x68\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f".unpack("Z*") --> "hello"
```

Comment: Duh... I was doing this: "\x61 \xcc \x83".unpack("Z*") (spaces)